# Collect Statistics on Glue Catalog tables

Tags: apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

In our project we use `AWS Glue Catalog` tables with the data stored on `S3` as `Parquet` files. We apply transformations (ETL) with `Spark-SQL` which reads data from these tables and derives the final result-set by creating multiple temporary views at every step.So, how do we collect statistics on these tables which can be used by Spark-SQL to generate better plans ?
I know that in Hive we can use `ANALYZE TABLE mytable COLLECT STATISTICS;` command to collect statistics. However, when I try the same command with the Glue Catalog tables, it throws an error - `Can not create path from an empty string.`
Can anyone please let me know how to collect stats on these glue tables ?

Sample Table DDL:

```
create table mydatabase.mytable
(
 empid integer,
 emp_name varchar(50),
 emp_age varchar(10)
)
STORED AS PARQUET
Location 'S3://some_path/somefolder';
```

PS: Please ignore syntax errors in DDL. Please let me know if additional information is necessary